# Deploying WCF Rest webservice to IIS 6.0 gives HTTP Error 404 - File or directory not found

Tags: wcf, rest, iis-6, wcf-rest

I have a WCF rest webservice that runs fine on my local VS2010 environment, but when deployed to IIS 6.0 on windows server 2003, I get the HTTP Error 404 - File or directory not found.
I've searched other threads with similar questions and tried all the suggestions to no avail.
Here's my service contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
 public interface IRestServiceImpl
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        UriTemplate = "Execute")]
    ExecuteResponse Execute(ExecuteRequest request);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        UriTemplate = "ExecutePutJSON")]
    ExecuteResponse ExecutePutJSON(ExecuteRequest request);
}
```

The implementation code behind (RestServiceImpl.svc.cs) is as follows:

```
public class RestServiceImpl : IRestServiceImpl
{
    public ExecuteResponse Execute(ExecuteRequest request)
    {
       //processing code that returns ExecuteResponse
    }

    public ExecuteResponse Execute(ExecuteRequest request)
    {
       //processing code that returns ExecuteResponse
    }
}
```

The RestServiceImpl.svc is as follows:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="CICJIS.IWS.RestServiceImpl" 
CodeBehind="RestServiceImpl.svc.cs" %>
```

The Web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel"
      switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing">
        <listeners>
          <add name="messages" />
        </listeners>
    </source>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
    <listeners>
      <add name="messages" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
 </sources>
 <sharedListeners>
  <add name="messages"
     type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
     initializeData="C:\Logs\RestService.svclog" />
 </sharedListeners>
 <trace autoflush="true" />
 </system.diagnostics>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" defaultLanguage="c#" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="999999" maxQueryStringLength="999999"
    executionTimeout="999"/>
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
   <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging
        logEntireMessage="true"
        logMalformedMessages="true"
        logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
        logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"
        maxMessagesToLog="3000"
        maxSizeOfMessageToLog="10000000" />
    </diagnostics>

   <services>
      <service name="RestServiceImpl" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IRestServiceImpl" 
          behaviorConfiguration="web">

        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>

      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

I have tried the following:

1.) installed the ASP.net 4.0 using aspnet_regiis -i
2.) Ran C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation>Service
ModelReg.exe -i
3.)manually changed the .svc extension mapping in the properties of the website for .svc to point to c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll
4.)In directory security unchecked the integrated windows authentication.
5.)Changed the ASP.net version from 2.0 to 4.0 on the website properties.

I have another WCF SOAP webservice deployed to the same server and IIS and I can browse and connect to it fine. I don't understand why I am unable to browse this WCF rest service or connect to it.

Any help is appreciated!!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I wanted to add that I tried to publish my webservice to my local IIS 7 and all I had to do to get it working is change the app pool to ASP.net 4.0.3 and run the ServiceModelReg -i. I copied the webservice folder created under inetput/wwwroot when I published from VS2010 to the windows server 2003 box running IIS 6 and still not able to get it running. :( Please help!!

Comment: I have additional information on this. I see the following error in the event viewer: Could not detect ASP.NET installation or ASP.NET is disabled, skipping the Web Host Script Mappings component since it depends upon ASP.NET to function properly.
If you believe this message is an error, check your ASP.NET installation to make sure it is installed properly and is the correct version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I solved my issue. I just re-ran the following steps a couple of times and it seemed to have fixed my problem. I am able to get to my Rest webservice now.

1. installed the ASP.net 4.0 using aspnet_regiis -i
2. Ran C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation>Service ModelReg.exe -i

Comment: I solved problem by changing your 1. step to aspnet_regiis -i -enable